# How to configure firewall for ftp?

Tags: iis, ftp, firewall, windows-server, windows-firewall

I have got ftp working for isolate users on a windows web server running iis 7.0

I am using coffecup as ftp client to connect.

when i turn off the firewall on the server the ftp works fine. I can connect to server.

As soon as i turn on firewall i get error:

```
There was a problem connecting to your host or proxy. Please check your server settings and try again. If you are sure you have entered the correct information, please contact your network administrator or the server administrator. [7] Additional information: couldn't connect to host.
```

On firewall i have port 20 and 21 open. What else am i missing? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing passive mode operation of FTP. In passive mode you're connecting to servers port that is negotiated over port 21.

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”FTP Service” action=allow service=ftpsvc protocol=TCP dir=in`

`netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable`

More info here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd421710%28v=ws.10%29.aspx